# How to make multiple database operations atomic/one transaction in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, atomic, transactionscope

I need to make the code below atomic/fail or succeed as a single unit. How could I go about achieving that?

```
void Processor(Input input)
{
    var mapper = new Mapper(recordDetails);
    int remainingRecords = GetCountForRemainingRecords(recordDetails);
    try
    {
        while (remainingRecords > 0)
        {
            mapper.CreateRecords(dataset);
            Validate(dataset);
            //the Save(dataset) uses SqlBulkCopy maps tables, transaction, and saves it..
            Save(dataset);
            //I cannot perform the operation below on the dataset directly because dataset doesn't have the records that is in the database
            //the method below eventually calls a stored proc that sends a list of users that was recently created
            OutdateDuplicateUsers(dataset.userTable);
            remainingRecords = MethodToGetUpdatedCount();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //exception handler..
    }
}
```

Now if my OutdateDuplicateUsers throws an exception, I would still end up with the accounts that Save method persisted. I do not want that to happen.
I want both Save and OutdateDuplicateUsers method to be atomic. I read about [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/690136/All-About-TransactionScope) great article about TransactionScope and seemed it is exactly what I want. However, I could not get it to work. The implementation seems straight forward reading from the article, but I couldn't get it working myself.

What I tried:

```
void Processor(Input input)
{
    var mapper = new Mapper(recordDetails);
    int remainingRecords = GetCountForRemainingRecords(recordDetails);
    try
    {
        while (remainingRecords > 0)
        {
            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    mapper.CreateRecords(dataset);
                    Validate(dataset);
                    //the method Save(dataset) is using SqlBulkCopy; maps tables, uses transaction, and saves it..
                    Save(dataset);
                    //I cannot perform this opertaion on the dataset directly because dataset doesn't have the records that is in the database
                    //the method below eventually calls a stored proc that sends a list of users that was recently created
                    OutdateDuplicateUsers(dataset.userTable);
                    remainingRecords = MethodToGetUpdatedCount();
                    scope.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    //not both at the same time. I tried using both, one at a time though.
                    TransactionScope.Dispose();
                    TransactionScope.Current.Rollback();
                    //exception handler
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

update:
The dataset is a strongly typed dataset and is schema only. The CreateRecords and Validate method populates the data based on the business logic. The 'mapper' takes in recordDetails which is, for instance, a list of Users (updated the snippet).
What I mean by doesn't work is that if OutdateDuplicateUser() method throws an exception and cannot complete the outdating operation, I could still see that the records have been persisted in the database from Save(dataset) method, which I am trying to prevent.

Comment: You don't have to call `TransactionScope.Dispose();` nor `TransactionScope.Current.Rollback();` to rollback the transaction. It's enough no to call `scope.Complete()` and the transaction should be rolled back when application exists the `using` block.

Comment: wouldn't you want to Rollback the transaction before disposing it plus since it's in a using statement you would not need to explicitly call Dispose method anyway..

Comment: If removing code from the `catch` section doesn't solve Your issue, Please also take note that it may depend on how the methods You call (for example `OutdateDuplicateUsers` or `Save`) are implementedand if they are *compatible* with `TransactionScope`.

Comment: when you say the transcation isn't working, could you elaborate? what are you using to retrive data from and update to the database? LINQ?

Comment: @MethodMan - yep, you are correct. I didn't realize that I was already using the Using statement. Anyways, I initially tried without any of the code in the Catch block and that didn't give me what I was expecting, so I tried few tweaks, which didn't work either.

Comment: @dochoffiday - please take a moment to look at the updated details on the question.

Comment: @Lukasz M - how do I found out if the statements are compatible?

Comment: You can try to debug the code to make sure the underlying SQL connection (for example for `dataSet`) uses the transaction that is provided with the `TransactionScope` block. The `dataSet` is created outside the transaction scope's `using` block, which may cause them not to use the transaction automatically.

Comment: You can also consider using `SqlTransaction` instead of `TransactionScope`, which in this particular case may be easier. A sample solution is described here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16410/C-Avoiding-DTC-with-Typed-DataSets-and-SQL-Server